# Linear programming model

Tags: linear-programming

I am writing a linear programming model with two decision variables for the follow scenario but am having trouble structuring it.  Here is the set up:
A company is going to rent machines that produce widgets and has $\$5000$ to spend.  Large machines can produce 200 widgets/month that costs $\$300$ / month.  Small machines produce 80 widgets/month and costs $\$1000$ for an initial down payment and $\$100$/month. The company needs to produce 1000 widgets/month.  We want to create two linear programs:

1. minimize total monthly payments and then
2. maximize monthly production capacity

My initial **setup** is:

$x_1$: Number of large machines

$x_2$: Number of small machines

Minimize monthly payments: $300  x_1 + (100 x_2 + 1000) /x_2$

**Constraints**:

Cost: $300x_1 + (100x_2 + 1000)/x_2 ≤ 5000$

Widget: $200x_1 + 80x_2 ≥ 1000$

For question 2) Maximize: $200x_1 + 80x_2$
Same constraints.

This should be able to be written as a linear programming problem by the cost constraint is not linear.

What am I missing?

Comment: The monthly payment is $300x_1+100x_2+1000$. What you have written for the small machines are the average cost.